# Control "readonly or notify" alert in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file that as several functionalities in vba. One of those is some background savings at some points. For that matter, the file must be able to write, or in other words, it cannot and should not function if its open as a readonly.

Hence my question: can I, and how, control the readonly (or notify) alert message, so that once the file is opened, it can warn (msgbox or form) that the file is opened, but prevent from going futher (like fully open as a readonly)?

There are some examples as how to check if a file is opened, from another file. This case, the file must check it self if opened, what I suspect that would render it in a loop. If the file could still retreive the user that opened the file in the first place (like the original warning), it would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a check in the `Workbook_Open()` event like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If ThisWorkbook.ReadOnly = True Then
    MsgBox "File in use by: " & CreateObject("ADsSecurityUtility").GetSecurityDescriptor(ThisWorkbook.FullName, 1, 1).Owner & _
        vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        "Please re-open this workbook when available for write access.", vbOkOnly + vbInformation, "File Locked"
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False '// close if read only
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you still could use the `Activeworkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite` to set the `ReadOnly` to `False` (it will be no more readonly starting from that point). but it will error if `ReadOnly` is already `False` or if you have only Read-Access to the drive etc... or use `Activeworkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly` to prevent changes (this also need a check or it will cause an error) ;)

Comment: Ok Macro Man. I'll give it a go! The only thing, about the loop that I was saying prior, is that if that check is done by Excel before the "readonly" alert is displayed (that being the vba custom code before the Excel standard code), it will never detect a readonly opened file. But nothing like trying. About the username, won't it give the user his own username back, instead of the username that has the file opened in the first place? I would like to have the chance to display the user that has the file opened, so someone can contact him if needed, to close the file.

Comment: Ok. So it works like fine. Thanks. Nevertheless, and as a follow up, the "readonly" check from excel is done prior (and the alert displayed) to your vba code. So, in that matter, the username of the user that first opened the file ends up by being visible. Still, its always good to have the first opener username available. The rest functions well and stops the file from opening. Thanks.